# Is findViewById give an unique (static) instance?

Tags: android, android-layout

From [findViewById 's document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29):
   `Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.`

But I don't know what is behind the scenes. 
For example, if I have a `TextView` in layout xml like this:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then I get this TextView in code:

```
TextView txt1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
     txt1.setText("Some text");
 }
```

In another place (maybe in button onClickListener), I get this TextView again:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

   TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
   Log.d(TAG,"txt2: " + txt2.getText().toString());
   Log.d(TAG,"txt1: " + txt1.getText().toString());
   //Change txt2 text
   txt2.setText("aaa");
   Log.d(TAG,"txt2: " + txt2.getText().toString());
   Log.d(TAG,"txt1: " + txt1.getText().toString());
   //change txt1 text
   txt1.setText("bbb");
   Log.d(TAG,"txt2: " + txt2.getText().toString());
   Log.d(TAG,"txt1: " + txt1.getText().toString());
  }
});
```

And here is the result:

```
txt2: Some text
txt1: Some text
txt2: aaa
txt1: aaa
txt2: bbb
txt1: bbb
```

Could you explain that? Is findViewById only give a static instance?

Comment: what is the point of this question? `findViewById` will return instance of first `View` with given id so if you search within the same view and you give same id you'll get the same view

Comment: I just confuse why I get the same result in 2 instances. Now I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily find out that you get exactly same objects in debugger (Variables -> Value column -> Id)
It's not a STATIC object it's just a single object, when you get one instance of activity you get one instance of this view, view will be recreated only when activity will be recreated.

In other words until activity recreated you always get same object when you call `findViewById`, so better practice is to get it once in `onCreate()` and reuse variable.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just confuse why I get the same result in 2 instances. Thank very much

Answer (score 3):

`txt2`, `txt1` points to `same Id` means same object of `TextView` which as id as `txt` so this behavior is bound to happen